# restclient errors "failed with code 111"

Tags: debugging, restclient

When I run `GET http://localhost/` with [`restclient.el`](https://github.com/pashky/restclient.el), I get the following error in the `*Messages*` buffer:

```
GET http://localhost:80/]
Contacting host: localhost:80
error in process sentinel: restclient-http-handle-response: peculiar error: "failed with code 111
", :host, "localhost", :service, 80
error in process sentinel: peculiar error: "failed with code 111
", :host, "localhost", :service, 80
```

Note the repeated error on the single invocation.

When I run `(setq debug-on-message "failed with code 111")` I get the following backtrace:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: "error in process sentinel: peculiar error: \"failed with code 111
\", :host, \"localhost\", :service, 80"
  recursive-edit()
  debug(error "error in process sentinel: peculiar error: \"failed with code 111\n\", :host, \"localhost\", :service, 80")
```

What is code 111, and how can I fix the failure?

Answer (score 3):

Error 111 refers to Linux system error `ECONNREFUSED` (connection refused), defined in `errno.h`.

This is not a problem with Emacs. Rather, the socket at `localhost:80` is refusing the connection, possibly because no web server is running.